# Иероглифы вместо русского языка в VSCode в окне Output

Tags: visual-studio-code

В VSCode именно в окне Output при выбранном .NET Test Log вместо русских букв выводит иероглифы. Именно в output, ни в debug console ни в terminal, там все на удивление нормально. 
Я так понимаю, это OmniSharp бесится.

Кто-нибудь знает как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианта 2:

1)

```
REG ADD HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot^%_system32_cmd.exe /v CodePage /t REG_DWORD /d 65001
```

2)

В Win10 в сборке 1809 надо зайти в настройки языка там выбрать "Административные языковые параметры", далее "Изменить язык системы" и там поставить галочку "Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод для поддержки языка во всем мире"

Сработал один из них, какой точно уже не установить.